# VB6 code to open a .exe file

Tags: vb6

I want to open a .exe file from the location "D:\abc.exe". what should be the VB6 code?

I need just the VB6. When I will click on a button it will run abc.exe file

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 5):

You need the shell command as described https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242087(v=vs.60).aspx

```
Shell "d:\abc.exe", vbNormalFocus
```

will probably do.